# Urllib2 .read() hangs when accessing a .csv file from HTTP

Tags: python, http, urllib

I am trying to use urllib2 to access .csv files which are posted at a specific http address. The code that I am using worked ~1 month ago but now will hang sporadically on the .read() command. I've done various tests to try to pin down the culprit. The address I am trying to access is publically available weather data from:

http://climate.weatheroffice.gc.ca/climateData/bulkdata_e.html?StationID=47267&hlyRange=2008-07-15|2013-03-20&timeframe=1&Prov=ONT&format=csv&Year=2008&Day=15&Month=9

The .readline() function works every time, and so I wrote the following test to see where the read process ends in the file:

```
foo=urllib2.urlopen(HTTPadress)
for i in range(1000): print i,dd.readline()
```

This will print out each line until the program hangs.  If it hangs it will be at the same line each time,and there are no special formatting or characters at this line (usually around line 680). For different datafiles, it will hang at a different line, but always the same one for the same file.

The code that I am actually using is part of a larger function which is used to loop through multiple datafiles:

```
def qry(query):
data =   urllib2.urlopen('http://climate.weatheroffice.gc.ca/climateData/bulkdata_e.html?'+query)
    print 'done'
    #pdb.set_trace()
    time.sleep(5)
    tmp=data.read()
    return tmp
```

the sleep function between the urlopen and read functions seemed to improve reliability for a while, and this function generally works when I run it through pdb. At this point, i'm fairly convinced that something has changed on the server end which is interfering with the .read() function, but I have no idea what this is and how to work around it.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm confused. You say "the .readline() function works every time", but then you say that it hangs at a certain line. Those can't both be true.

Comment: You might want to try printing out the _byte_ count, instead of the _line_ count. I'd give better than even odds that the byte count is the same for every resource, and the only reason the line count is different is that different resources with different content obviously have different-length lines.

Comment: Also, does it actually fail on the one example URL you gave? Because I can run that over and over again, See http://pastebin.com/1BrRQuHB. When I run this, it just prints `99929 737` once/second until I hit ^C. Does it work for you? If so, do you have a URL it _doesn't_ work for?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. The first few .readline() calls work, but if it hangs, it will eventually hang at an arbitrary line. I tried your code and for me, it works sometimes and then will hang at 90027 bytes for one file and 89982 for the other. The most I got it to do was three file reads in a row before hanging, so it looks like there might be an issue with how I am accessing the server from my end, if this is working for you. (If you want to try a different file, you can change the year= parameter to between 2008-2013)

Comment: Instead of just saying that it works on some files and not on others, and that distinction is repeatable, please tell me which URL it hangs on at 90027, which URL it hangs on at 89982, etc. Just saying that there exists some URL for which it hangs at 90027 does not help me to debug it. (I tried all 6 of the possible variations on `year=`, and they all worked. But I have no idea if any of them are URLs that hang for you, so I have no idea if that means anything or not.)

Comment: I tried this code on an external computer, and it worked fine for all URL's, so it looks like this is likely a router issue. I'll update if I figure out what the settings were that are interfering with urllib. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the server is not properly honoring the `Connection: close` header in the request urllib2 sends.  Have you tried using the `timeout` arg to `urllib.urlopen`?  I'm not sure if it will affect the `read()` operation, though, or if it is limited to the actual connection attempt.

Comment: I just set the socket timeout using socket.setdefaulttimeout(10). Now instead of hanging the request will time-out. So, the hanging is solved but it didn't help the file retrieval.

Comment: You can obviously set the timeout _longer_. But if the server is just not responding, and you're sending a valid request, there really isn't much you can do but fail and skip or retry that URL. If it consistently fails to respond 100% of the time on the same URL, retrying won't help either; there is really _nothing_ you can do if a server isn't working.

Comment: Yes, and i'll try running overnight with no timeout and see what falls out. Overall, the frustrating part of this is that if I do two calls right after eachother, one will go through immediately, and the next one will hang. It seems like a server inconsistency, but I was wondering if there was anything in urllib that could cause that sort of inconsistency.

Comment: @Robandrews: Before going away overnight, you might want to try answering all the questions that I asked. That way, you might come back to an answer (whether from me, or someone else) instead of another round of frustration.